# when i have install i didn't find tailwind file and is it required to install tailwind

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, hadoop-yarn

> [plugin:vite:css] [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'config')
> /Users/vipulkumarsingh/Desktop/test/main/src/App.css
> at getTailwindConfig (/Users/vipulkumarsingh/node_modules/**tailwindcss**/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:87:62)
> at /Users/vipulkumarsingh/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:99:92
> at /Users/vipulkumarsingh/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:48:11
> at plugins (/Users/vipulkumarsingh/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/plugin.js:38:63)
> at LazyResult.runOnRoot (/Users/vipulkumarsingh/Desktop/test/main/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:357:16)
> at LazyResult.runAsync (/Users/vipulkumarsingh/Desktop/test/main/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:286:26)
> at LazyResult.async (/Users/vipulkumarsingh/Desktop/test/main/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:160:30)
> at LazyResult.then (/Users/vipulkumarsingh/Desktop/test/main/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:436:17

i didn't find tailwinf when i had  install yarn i have to **npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer vite for installing tailwind**  The below command will generate 2 config files named postcss.config.js and tailwind.config.js.

**npx tailwindcss init -p** by this problem got resolved  but i don't want to use tailwind in my project